# Could not load or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, version=2016.1.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=1cee9fbde3db106'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ssh, database-connection, filenotfoundexception

The strServer is IP is of another pc which connected in LAN, and Also server is Turned ON in another PC.

Here is my code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Dim strServer As String = "192.168.1.2"
    Dim strDB As String = "lab_utilization"
    Dim struser As String = "root"
    Dim strPw As String = ""

    Dim cs As String = "Server=" & strServer & ";Port=3306;Database=" & strDB & ";uid=" & struser & ";Pwd=" & strPw & ";"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(cs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into PC values('Adi101','Adi101')", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = cs
        con.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

While Executing Code i get following error on con.open()

```
Could not load or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, version=2016.1.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=1cee9fbde3db106' or one of its dependecies. the system cannot find the specified
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is. If that file is not present, it's not going to be able to load it. You need to make some sort of effort before posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  thanks but if you can help me that  how i can fix this it would be great and btw I'm beginner

Comment: What do you not understand about the information you found when you searched the web? SO should be your last resort, not your first option.